# Xpath selection only returns first response result

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors, items

I'm still new to scrapy. When trying to read data from ***quotes.toscrape***, I don't get any content back when using xpath selectors. As soon as I use css selectors everything works as intended. I just can't find the error even though the example is super simple.

**quotes.py**

```
import scrapy
from quotes_loader.items import QuotesLoaderItem as QL

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com//']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = QL()
        quotes = response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]')

        for quote in quotes:
            # CSS-Selector
            # item['author_name'] = quote.css('small.author::text').get()
            # item['quote_text'] = quote.css('span.text::text').get()
            # item['author_link'] = quote.css('small.author + a::attr(href)').get()
            # item['tags'] = quote.css('div.tags > a.tag::text').get()

            # XPATH-Selektor
            item['author_name'] = quote.xpath('//small[@class="author"]/text()').get()
            item['quote_text'] = quote.xpath('//span[@class="text"]/text()').get()
            item['author_link'] = quote.xpath('//small[@class="author"]/following-sibling::a/@href').get()
            item['tags'] = quote.xpath('//*[@class="tags"]/*[@class="tag"]/text()').get()

            yield item

        # next_page_url = response.css('li.next > a::attr(href)').get()
        next_page_url = response.xpath('//*[class="next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(absolute_next_page_url)
```

**items.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class QuotesLoaderItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    author_name = scrapy.Field()
    quote_text = scrapy.Field()
    author_link = scrapy.Field()
    tags = scrapy.Field()
```

**Result**

```
author_name,quote_text,author_link,tags
Albert Einstein,“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”,/author/Albert-Einstein,change
Albert Einstein, ...
...
(20 times)
```

thank you for your commitment

Comment: Could you include a sample url you're running it against?

Comment: @Forensic_07 
Hey. I don't understand. The Python script has a URL from which it scraps the data. (allowed_domains and start_urls)

Comment: My mistake, I thought it was a fake url! Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I use a selector object instead of a respons object and therefore the syntax has to look like this.

```
import scrapy
from quotes_loader.items import QuotesLoaderItem as QL

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com//']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = QL()
        quotes = response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]')

        for quote in quotes:
            # CSS-Selector
            # item['author_name'] = quote.css('small.author::text').get()
            # item['quote_text'] = quote.css('span.text::text').get()
            # item['author_link'] = quote.css('small.author + a::attr(href)').get()
            # item['tags'] = quote.css('div.tags > a.tag::text').get()
            
            # XPATH-Selector
            item['author_name'] = quote.xpath('.//small[@class="author"]/text()').get()
            item['quote_text'] = quote.xpath('.//span[@class="text"]/text()').get()
            item['author_link'] = quote.xpath('.//small[@class="author"]/following-sibling::a/@href').get()
            item['tags'] = quote.xpath('.//*[@class="tags"]/*[@class="tag"]/text()').get()

            yield item

        # next_page_url = response.css('li.next > a::attr(href)').get()
        next_page_url = response.xpath('.//*[class="next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(absolute_next_page_url)
```